# iconv() не переводит некоторые символы

Tags: php, iconv

При преобразовании строки из кодировки "utf-8" в "windows-1251" iconv() ничего не выдаёт. Думаю, что это из-за символов типа "☕". Как это решить?

Comment: Почитайте официальную доку на iconv в php: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php  особенно про out_charset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не используйте кодировку windows-1251, на дворе уже почти 2017 год.
**P.S.** А если сильно надо, то делайте это так, например:

```
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251//IGNORE', $str);
```

> Если добавить к out_charset строку //TRANSLIT, включается режим транслитерации. Это значит, что в случае, если символ не может быть представлен в требуемой кодировке, он будет заменен на один или несколько нескольких наиболее близких по внешнему виду символов. Если добавить строку //IGNORE, то символы, которые не могут быть представлены в требуемой кодировке, будут удалены. В случае отсутствия вышеуказанных параметров при наличии некорректных символов строка str будет обрезана до первого такого символа, будет сгенерирована ошибка уровня E_NOTICE и функция вернет FALSE.

[Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

Comment: Всё работает. PHP использую не в традиционных целях, а для создания GUI-программ. В среде программирования, в которой я работаю есть поддержка только Windows-1251. Так что приходиться пользоваться ей.

Comment: Помню, как лет 6-7 смотрел туториалы и там говорили `Не используйте utf` это ненадежно и пр, используйте только windows-1251 xD  Идут года, всё меняется))